# How to tag a pic with people in a tweet

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Since 2014, Twitter makes it possible to send a tweet with pics that have Twitter users tagged in them ([ref](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/photos-just-got-more-social)).

How can I do that through the Twitter API, and with Twitter4j if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they have released this as a feature of their App but have not released any API's for the same till now.

You can check following [forum](https://twittercommunity.com/t/photo-api-status/16913) which mentions Photo Tagging API is not publicly available yet. As per official update from twitter staff on 17th April, this is not made public yet. You can follow @twitterapi / @TwitterDev to get updates about new API's they add.